# Is there any restriction on what constitutes a mezuzah case?

Tags: mezuzah, protective-casing

A friend would like to make a mezuzah case for me, but has never made one before.  Are there any restrictions on its construction or design?

Comment: See [this pair of articles](http://www.thehalacha.com/attach/Volume4/Issue6.pdf) about [how to affix a Mezuzah](http://www.thehalacha.com/attach/Volume4/Issue8.pdf) for some pointers that may shed light on what type of construction may be required.

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65263

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73374

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would argue the following.  A mezuzua case needs to be constructed so that the halachot of hanging a mezuza can be followed.

1. The casing should have a clear "top", so that the mezuzah can be hung appropriately (not upside down).
2. The casing should be taller than it is wide.
3. The casing should have an opening large enough for a scroll, so that the scroll can be rolled, and not bent or shoved.
4. The casing should not look like some other religion's or religious symbol that is often hung on doors or walls, so that it is clear that it is a mezuzah.  (For example, I don't think you could make it into a cross, or horseshoe, or a standard Chamtza)
5. The casing needs to be weatherproof so that there is no danger of the scroll getting damaged.

Regarding opacity. In Israel they have a few "standard" mezuza cases, these cases are all the same shape and come in white, black, brown, silver.. [AND transparent](http://www.weissjudaica.com/system/scripts/results_big.cgi?product=216). So I don't see what is wrong with a transparent mezuza as hudreds of people have them.

Comment: also, the case should be openable so you can inspect it every seven years or so.

Comment: if it's totaly waterproof and hung inside it probobly never needs to be checked

Comment: BTW: Once is not allowed to HANG a mezuza (with or w/o a case) - it has to be AFFIXED. (Hang: usually defined as connected by a single nail near the top.)

Answer (score 11):

1. It would be a good idea to provide your friend with the dimensions of the actual mezuza you plan on using, to ensure that the cavity inside the case will be large enough to accommodate it without having to compress it.
2. If it will be exposed to the elements, it **must** be waterproof and durable.

Comment: Re: 1 I've received, more than once, little tiny mezuza covers as gifts. Unfortunately, the mezuzot that would fit in them are more expensive and also more error-prone, since they need to be written with tiny letters.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the answers already given:

- There must be a way to attach it to the doorpost or wall. So if you don't want to cover it with tape then it has to be lightweight enough, and of a material, that double-sided tape will hold it to the doorpost or wall, or it has to allow nails or something to hold it to a surface.
- The *m'zuza* (scroll) should not fall out of it when it's upright. Any opening should be made with that in mind. (Of course, if the case will be exposed to the elements, then, as [Dave's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8716) mentioned, it should protect the *m'zuza* from those elements, so there'll likely be no opening anyway.)

Answer (score 4):

One that comes to mind is that if the *m'zuza* is within eyeshot of anything disgusting or unbecoming, the case should be opaque so as not to expose the scroll to the unbecoming thing. ([*KSA* 11:18](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%90#.28.D7.99.D7.97.29))

Comment: Source, please? (_KSA_ doesn't mention opacity AFAICT.)

Comment: Do we usually require opaque covers when something needs to be covered (e.g. taking a holy book into the bathroom)?

Comment: @msh210 - Are you suggesting that the "covering" he is talking about is not a line-of-sight obstruction but one to prevent coming in contact?

Comment: @WAF, not contact necessarily (as physical contact is unlikely in any event), but perhaps there needs to be a separation and transparency doesn't matter.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, the "Ask Question" link, above, is red and hard to miss. `;-)`

Comment: @msh210 - My question's worth asking more generally, but I only brought it up here as a challenge to WAF's interpretation of this halacha.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I wouldn't put it past us. But I believe I can find a source for the _m'zuza_ specifically. Although the _Kitzur Shulchan Aruch_ is actually not my primary source for opacity, it did not occur to me that it wasn't referring to that requirement until @msh210 and you challenged it.

Comment: @msh210 [Done.](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8735/what-qualities-are-necessary-in-a-halachic-wrapping)

Comment: [avi's](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8714/is-there-any-restriction-on-what-constitutes-a-mezuzah-case/8727#8727) minhag Yisrael argument adds to the necessity to find a clear ;^) source for this requirement.

Comment: My rabbi told me, during Chatan classes that one must close their door so that the mezuzah is not visible.  He didn't seem to indicate that this is only true with a transparent mezuzah casing.  So unless he was just wrong, it seems that the whole mezuzah needs to avoid unbecoming things.