# Is there a standard for what type of casing a mezuzah needs to be made from?

Tags: mezuzah, disposal, holy-objects

[I very recently came across a mezuzah made from recycled material.](https://www.repairthesea.org/product-page/tikkun-hayam-mezuzah?fbclid=IwAR3n1Vnfx2fsjAG7h3qsb7kr8Kmi6EMHB3ZVyoC371ho5cXLCVQBlz5bPA0) The product is referred to as a ***Tikun Olam*** mezuzah case and they are apparently all made from reclaimed plastic from the ocean. *(the idea is you're cleaning the oceans while performing the mitzvah which they claim as a form of Tikun Olam)*

As much as I thought the idea was cool, it brought up a question I never really considered.

Is there a rabbinical standard for the type of housing/case you should use for a mezuzah? I've obviously seen mezuzah cases in a variety of materials.

- Wood
- Metal
- Stone
- Tile
- Etc.

That being said, would there be a concern of disrespecting the scroll if you place it inside of a mezuzah recycled from what is essentially trash?

Comment: See too https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73374/759

Comment: The mezuzah case is actually called "Tikkun Yam".