Can mezuzah case be slightly smaller than mezuzah?
B"H
I'm aware of this question:
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/74120/34286
And answer the says that really a mezuzah doesn't require a case, but for practical purposes one should put it in a reed etc so that it's steady, and in addition to being wrapped in plastic it should be protected by the elements etc, and one shouldn't kiss it without a case
I recently got a mezuzah case only to discover that it's too small for the mezuzah to fully fit it, but:
The mezuzah is wrapped in plastic
The doorway is inside and away from rain etc.
It's big enough to be held steady in the case even if not covered
Is this fine theoretically?


The picture of the case is upside down

While no case is required, it seems that Hidur Mitzva applies here, if there is a case it should be a suitable case.
