# Can a security camera be placed in a Mezuzah?

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, mezuzah

I saw this question posted on another forum and I didn't see any valid answers or conclusions.

If a person had a Mezuzah case which was fitted with a hidden security camera, would that impact the status of the Mezuzah in any way?

What if the camera was being used to prevent antisemitic harassment to help ensure the Jew could observe? ***(to prevent the Mezuzah from being damaged or stolen)*** Would that have any relevance in the situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8714/759 ping Isaac @Alex

Comment: I've seen many mezuzah cases that are larger than the part that opens to receive the scroll.  It would be very easy to design one with a camera.  Nowadays we have camera doorbells.  They're small, connected to power, and transmit to an app on your phone.

Comment: 1) By "Mezuzah," you refer to the mezuzah case, correct? The whole thing is just to protect the Klaf. There are no halachot about it...
2) If you're afraid of the Mezuzah being stolen or damaged, then you're probably not obligated in the first place. See Yoreh Deah 286:1